# Pandas: Filtering multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to do boolean indexing with a couple conditions using Pandas.  My original DataFrame is called `df`.  If I perform the below, I get the expected result:

```
temp = df[df["bin"] == 3]
temp = temp[(~temp["Def"])]
temp = temp[temp["days since"] > 7]
temp.head()
```

However, if I do this (which I think should be equivalent), I get no rows back:

```
temp2 = df[df["bin"] == 3]
temp2 = temp2[~temp2["Def"] & temp2["days since"] > 7]
temp2.head()
```

Any idea what accounts for the difference?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Use `()` because [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence):

```
temp2 = df[~df["Def"] & (df["days since"] > 7) & (df["bin"] == 3)]
```

Alternatively, create conditions on separate rows:

```
cond1 = df["bin"] == 3    
cond2 = df["days since"] > 7
cond3 = ~df["Def"]

temp2 = df[cond1 & cond2 & cond3]
```

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Def':[True] *2 + [False]*4,
                   'days since':[7,8,9,14,2,13],
                   'bin':[1,3,5,3,3,3]})

print (df)
     Def  bin  days since
0   True    1           7
1   True    3           8
2  False    5           9
3  False    3          14
4  False    3           2
5  False    3          13


temp2 = df[~df["Def"] & (df["days since"] > 7) & (df["bin"] == 3)]
print (temp2)
     Def  bin  days since
3  False    3          14
5  False    3          13
```

Comment: This is getting so much better with samples!

Comment: no parentheses for the first condition? This seems to change things for me.

Comment: If you have a LARGE DataFrame each of the conditions is filtering the *complete* DataFrame. Can you successively reduce the search space by chaining the filters? e.g. aplly the first, apply the second to *that* result, ...?

Comment: @wwii if really huge dataframe thwn you are right. first filter by condition which remove the most rows, assign to dataframe. then filter by second and similar...

Comment: @wwii do it means here `temp1 = df[df["bin"] == 3]
temp2 = temp1[temp1["days since"] > 7]
temp3 = temp2[~temp2["Def"]]`

Comment: What would be the efficient way when you have a large number of condition values.
for example `df[(df.col1==0) & (df.col2==1) & (df.col3==1)]` has 3 column conditions, but what if there are 50 column condition values?
is there any easy way where you put the columns and condition values as 2 lists

something simpler like `column_list= df.columns[11:61]
value_list= 'a list of 50 values'
df[df[column_list]== value_list]`

Answer (score 11):

**OR**

```
 df_train[(df_train["fold"]==1) | (df_train["fold"]==2)]
```

**AND**

```
 df_train[(df_train["fold"]==1) & (df_train["fold"]==2)]
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you can use the method [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
df.query('not Def & (`days since` > 7) & (bin == 3)')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want multiple conditions:

```
Del_Det_5k_top_10 = Del_Det[(Del_Det['State'] == 'NSW') & (Del_Det['route'] == 2) |
                            (Del_Det['State'] == 'VIC') & (Del_Det['route'] == 3)]
```