# Pandas & filtering

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have an error

`**'ufunc 'bitwise_and' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe'**`

when I am attempting to filter by my code :

`(xls[xls['DisabilityFriendly'] == 'приспособлен для всех групп инвалидов']) & (xls[xls['Paid'] == 'бесплатно'])`

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48978550/pandas-filtering-multiple-conditions)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
xls[(xls['DisabilityFriendly'] == 'приспособлен для всех групп инвалидов') & (xls['Paid'] == 'бесплатно')]
```

Look at where the brackets `[]` and `()` are.

Differences:

```
(xls[xls['DisabilityFriendly'] == 'приспособлен для всех групп инвалидов']) & (xls[xls['Paid'] == 'бесплатно'])
xls[(xls['DisabilityFriendly'] == 'приспособлен для всех групп инвалидов') & (xls['Paid'] == 'бесплатно')]
```