# Replacing values in a pandas dataframe based on multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a fairly simple question based on this sample code:

```
x1 = 10*np.random.randn(10,3)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(x1)
```

I am looking for a single DataFrame derived from `df1` where positive values are replaced with `"up"`, negative values are replaced with `"down"`, and `0` values, if any, are replaced with `"zero"`. I have tried using the `.where()` and `.mask()` methods but could not obtain the desired result.

I have seen other posts which filter according to multiple conditions at once, but they do not show how to replace values according to different conditions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas: Filtering multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48978550/pandas-filtering-multiple-conditions)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general, you could use `np.select` on the `values` and re-build the `DataFrame`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame(10*np.random.randn(10, 3))
df1.iloc[0, 0] = 0 # So we can check the == 0 condition 

conds = [df1.values < 0 , df1.values > 0]
choices = ['down', 'up']

pd.DataFrame(np.select(conds, choices, default='zero'),
             index=df1.index,
             columns=df1.columns)
```

#### Output:

```
      0     1     2
0  zero  down    up
1    up  down    up
2    up    up    up
3  down  down  down
4    up    up    up
5    up    up    up
6    up    up  down
7    up    up  down
8  down    up  down
9    up    up  down
```

Answer (score 12):

For multiple conditions ie. `(df['employrate'] <=55) & (df['employrate'] > 50)`

use this:

```
df['employrate'] = np.where(
   (df['employrate'] <=55) & (df['employrate'] > 50) , 11, df['employrate']
   )
```

or you can do it this way as well,

```
gm.loc[(gm['employrate'] <55) & (gm['employrate'] > 50),'employrate']=11
```

here informal syntax can be:

```
<dataset>.loc[<filter1> & (<filter2>),'<variable>']='<value>'
```

---

```
out[108]:
       country  employrate alcconsumption
0  Afghanistan   55.700001            .03
1      Albania   11.000000           7.29
2      Algeria   11.000000            .69
3      Andorra         nan          10.17
4       Angola   75.699997           5.57
```

therefore syntax we used here is:

```
 df['<column_name>'] = np.where((<filter 1> ) & (<filter 2>) , <new value>, df['column_name'])
```

---

for single condition, ie. `( 'employrate'] > 70 )`

```
       country        employrate alcconsumption
0  Afghanistan  55.7000007629394            .03
1      Albania  51.4000015258789           7.29
2      Algeria              50.5            .69
3      Andorra                            10.17
4       Angola  75.6999969482422           5.57
```

use this:

```
df.loc[df['employrate'] > 70, 'employrate'] = 7
```

---

```
       country  employrate alcconsumption
0  Afghanistan   55.700001            .03
1      Albania   51.400002           7.29
2      Algeria   50.500000            .69
3      Andorra         nan          10.17
4       Angola    7.000000           5.57
```

therefore syntax here is:

```
df.loc[<mask>(here mask is generating the labels to index) , <optional column(s)> ]
```

---

Answer (score 8):

```
df1.apply(np.sign).replace({-1: 'down', 1: 'up', 0: 'zero'})
```

Output:

```
      0     1     2
0  down    up    up
1    up  down  down
2    up  down  down
3  down  down    up
4  down  down    up
5  down    up    up
6  down    up  down
7    up  down  down
8    up    up  down
9  down    up    up
```

P.S. Getting exactly zero with `randn` is pretty unlikely, of course

Comment: sleek solution @perl... but what if i need to compute operations with the ```df1``` dataframe (let's say, x + 20 if ```np.sign(x)==-1```) and not just replacement with character strings?

Comment: @ManuelF That kind of replacement would be easier done with `where`: `df.where(np.sign(df)!=-1, df + 20)` (note that it replaces values where the condition is false, hence the inversion)

Answer (score 4):

**IF condition with OR**

```
from pandas import DataFrame

names = {'First_name': ['Jon','Bill','Maria','Emma']}

df = DataFrame(names,columns=['First_name'])

df.loc[(df['First_name'] == 'Bill') | (df['First_name'] == 'Emma'), 'name_match'] = 'Match'  
df.loc[(df['First_name'] != 'Bill') & (df['First_name'] != 'Emma'), 'name_match'] = 'Mismatch'
print (df)
```

Output

```
  First_name name_match
0        Jon   Mismatch
1       Bill      Match
2      Maria   Mismatch
3       Emma      Match
```