# Pandas conditional slicing, using both "and" and "or"

Tags: python, pandas

This is just a quick question with a yes or no answer. I couldn't find an answer for on google or here (difficult to google).

I just want to know if I am doing this the correct way.

I am trying to select data matching certain conditions. Here is a snipped from my code.

```
c1 = (data['recency']<=3) # seen in the last 3 months
c2 = (data['transactions_per_month']>=1) # buys a ticket once a month
c3 = (data['av_spend_per_month']>=30) # spends at least €30 per month
c4 = (data['Driver']==1) # is a driver

# slice the df
data[c1 & (c2 | c3) & c4]
```

Is this part correct? `(c2 | c3)` Can I add a `|` condition in the middle of my `&` conditions?

If it is wrong, what is the correct way to do it?

Comment: Yes but it needs to be  like `data[ (col1>10)or (col2<10)]` i.e.passing the filters and not the fitered data. See mroe here  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing

Comment: Yes, you can. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48978550/pandas-filtering-multiple-conditions

Comment: @venky__ so you used `or` instead of `|`. Do I need to change the `|` to `or`?

Comment: Use the `operators( & | )` I should have written `|`

Comment: Should be safer: `data[((c1) & ((c2) | (c3))) & (c4)]` . The parentheses you have around condition definitions make it look like tuple object with series in it, which is why I put the parentheses again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is a perfectly reasonable thing to do.

According to the Pandas manual, you can combine multiple selectors using boolean operators such as `&`, `|`, and `~`.

> Another common operation is the use of boolean vectors to filter the data. The operators are: `|` for or, `&` for and, and `~` for not. These must be grouped by using parentheses, since by default Python will evaluate an expression such as `df['A'] > 2 & df['B'] < 3` as `df['A'] > (2 & df['B']) < 3`, while the desired evaluation order is `(df['A'] > 2) & (df['B'] < 3)`.

([Source](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing).)

You might also explore the [DataFrame.query()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) method, which can accomplish a similar thing.