# Iterate over a dictionary to search dataframe, filter by range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I am writing a small web page with streamlit, the user selects variables/criteria from dropdown/slider menu, and a dataframe is then searched by the criteria.

The criteria are in a dict like so:

```
    dict_choice = {'Site': 'Broadbent',
       'Cover': '53',
       'Weight': (1.9875, 5.9625),
       'SVL': (18.75, 56.25),
       'VTL': (22.25, 66.75),
       'Regen': (16.5, 49.5)}
```

At this point, I'd like to search the df, something like this:

```
   newdf = df.loc[(df['Site']==site_choice) &
           (df['Cover']==cover_choice) & 
           ((df['Weight']>=weight_choice[0]) & (df['Weight']<=weight_choice[1])) &
           ((df['VTL']>=vtl_choice[0]) & (df['VTL']<=vtl_choice[1])) &
           ((df['SVL']>=svl_choice[0]) & (df['SVL']<=svl_choice[1])) &
           ((df['Regen']>=regen_choice[0]) & (df['Regen']<=regen_choice[1]))
           ]
```

How do I iterate over the dictionary to make the search query? My main problem are the criteria which include a range.

I know that if there **wasn't a range**, I can do:

```
  results_df = df.loc[df[list(dict_choice.keys())].isin(list(dict_choice.values())).all(axis=1), :]
```

But no idea how to filter by range. Halp.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas: Filtering multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48978550/pandas-filtering-multiple-conditions)

Comment: Just a tip you can write comparisons like `df['Weight']>=weight_choice[0]) & (df['Weight']<=weight_choice[1]` as `weight_choice[0] <= df['Weight'] <= weight_choice[1]` . The second way is more pythonic.

Comment: Thanks @BeanBagTheCat, that does read better :)