# Python data summarize function

Tags: python

My problem is the following, I want to sum up all values of the column `new_results_reported`, which have the `Overall_Outcome` 'Positive' and belong to the state `Alabama`.

Filter out all columns that have the `state_name` Alabama, have an `overall_outcome` 'Positive' and display the sum of them in the column `new_results_reported`.

```
state_name                object
overall_outcome           object
date                      object
new_results_reported       int64
total_results_reported     int64
dtype: object
```

output of `new_results_reported` from state `Alabama` should be in Integer

I did some research and came up with something like:

```
for overall_outcome in table1:
    if overall_outcome != 'Positive':
```

Unfortunately, I have absolutely no idea how to set up functions or how to do it best.

I would appreciate your help very much.

[image: table view with colums]

Comment: is this related to pandas and dataframe?

Comment: Do you want the answer to be a single integer?

Comment: Hi, yes this is related to Panda and Df.

Comment: i want that i can see in state Alabama are 'x' ppl tested positive for the year 2020 only. Since in the table are also values from 2021

Comment: I did not understand what are you trying to say. Please explain more clearly what your output should look like by updating the question

Comment: Do alabama have values from 2021 also?

Comment: yes Alabama also has values from 2021. i try to specify my question give me a second

Comment: Also add the data types of all the columns. Is date datatype string?

Comment: where can i see the datatype. Im really sorry im a beginner

Comment: SO what your output should look like? Should it be integer of all the sum?

Comment: ah i found it i will post in question

Comment: yes output should be integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the hints that you have given in your question,the following code will do the work. Please research on some builtin python function like `zip` which will zip the elements of same index of many lists.

I assume that your dataframe name is `table1`

```py
total_sum = 0

for state_name, overall_outcome, dt, new_results_reported in zip(table1['state_name'].values.tolist(), table1['overall_outcome'].values.tolist(),table1['date'].values.tolist(), table1['new_results_reported'].values.tolist()):
  ndt = int(str(dt)[:4])
  if (state_name == 'Alabama') and (overall_outcome == 'Positive') and (ndt == 2020):
    total_sum += int(new_results_reported)

print(total_sum)
```

Comment: it worked perfectly thank you so much. how can i change the function if i want to see all new_results_reported from 2020 in the whole USA

Comment: For that, you have to add another condition which only checks for 2020 of Alabama

Comment: how can i define that. if i add " and (date=='2020') it doesnt work

Comment: Welcome. Try to understand the code so that you can do it yourself in future

Comment: can u look @ my question below if you have time to answer it

Answer (score 0):

i can roughly understand the codes. i just never understand how you get the codes. I have another problem.
I want to compare the case numbers of alabama 2020 now with case numbers of another state in a plot.

```
: for overall_outcome in table1:
    if overall_outcome != 'Positive':
        plt.plot(table1.date[1:10], table1.new_results_reported[1:10])
        plt.figure(figsize=(8,5))
```

everything is totally confusing, because it throws all the data in.

how can I display here only the data of Alabama 2020 and anothe state in comparison?

Comment: Are your data in a pandas dataframe ? if it is the case it should be easy to filter it.

Comment: yes my data is in a pandas df, but how can i filter it? i want the total amount of new_results_reported from each state in a new table

Comment: As you already accepted an answer, you should create a new different question, and show code of your pandas dataframe ... with column names and sample data.  Something like df[df['state_name']=='Alabama' & pd.DatetimeIndex(df['date']).year =='2020']. This is duplicate question of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48978550/pandas-filtering-multiple-conditions

Comment: i already opened a new question.. can u have a look? ans see if u can help me with that please