# Select dataframes rows based on an OR condition

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a df dataframe with one column named "Move", and I want to keep only the rows for which Move is "Right" or "Left".

But this doesn't work:

```
df = df[df.Move == 'Right' or df.Move == 'Left']
```

neither does this:

```
moves = ['Right','Left']
df = df[df.Move in moves]
```

Would you have any idea of how to do something like that?

Comment: Could you provide a sample of this DF?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are missing parenthesis,  try using this

`df = df.loc[(df.Move == "Right") & (df.Move == "Left")]`

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the world of try and error of Pandas :-)

```
df = df[(df.Move == 'Right') | (df.Move == 'Left')]
```

The explanation TLDR;

- Masks are boolean `Series`, hence, subject to bitwise operators OR `|`, AND `&` and NOT/XOR `^`

An answer from StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64939034/206413

**Edited**: parenthesis for clauses

Comment: Well, I tried this too, but it doesn't work either. It gives me : TypeError: Cannot perform 'ror_' with a dtyped [object] array and scalar of type [bool]

Comment: I found my mistake. I needed parenthesis, so it works with df = df[(df.Move == 'Right') | (df.Move == 'Left')]. Thanks you for your help.

Comment: @MVMV, yep, me too :-) I just edited my answer adding the parenthesis, after fiddling in the jupyter notebook :-) I hope you upvote my answer. I'm almost at 1000 points! Please, please, please...

Comment: I tried to upvote it, but the site tells me that I need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote or something. Maybe I can't do it because I just arrived on stakcoverflow? I'm definitely coming back to this post to upvote your answer as soon as I get 15 reputation, don't worry :)

Comment: @MVMV, thanks for trying! Thanks, thanks, thanks! I was in the same position years ago and now I try to reach 1000 points. Hope to help you reach 1000 points some time in the future :-) Enjoy the ride.