# Filter Pandas DF

Tags: python, pandas

I got a Dataframe with three columns: "Company", "Cost" and "Refund".

```
raw_df = pd.DataFrame({
'Company': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A'],
'Cost': [10, 10, 10, 0, 158],
'Refund': [0, 0, 0, 10, 0]})
```

If there has been a refund, then my goal is to remove the corresponding cost.
For the above example, the solution would be:

```
filtered_df = pd.DataFrame({
'Company': ['A', 'B', 'A'],
'Cost': [10, 10, 158],
'Refund': [0, 0, 0]})
```

How can you code it?

Clarification notes:

- A row can never have a cost and refund. It is always a cost OR a refund
- If there has been a refund, there will ALWAYS be a **matching** cost with a **matching** company.
- A single refund cancels only a **single** cost. Like in the example above.

Comment: Does it matter which row is removed -- first or second?

Comment: Doesn't really matter, but would be "nice" if it is the closest one.

Comment: Can a refund ever have a non-zero cost associated with it?

Comment: @wjandrea. If there is a refund, then there is ALWAYS a corresponding company with the EXACT corresponding cost.

Comment: Noting the cost is in a different transaction than the refund would have been helpful to understand what you need. Try using pd.change.shift(-1) to access a previous row.

Comment: @crystal Sorry, I mean, can a refund ever have a cost in the same row?

Comment: @wjandrea, no they are always separated. A row can never have a cost and refund. It is always a cost OR a refund.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas: Filtering multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48978550/pandas-filtering-multiple-conditions)

Comment: @itprorh66 No, OP only needs one condition, but they don't know what it would be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

self join the dataframes renaming refund to cost. then filter each company to keep the last index and drop them.

```
tmp = raw_df.drop("Cost",1).rename(columns={"Refund":"Cost"}).query("Cost > 0")
tmp1 = raw_df.merge(tmp.reset_index(),on=['Company','Cost'],how='left')\
            .dropna(subset=['index']).drop_duplicates(["Company","index"],keep='last')
filtered_df = raw_df.drop(sum(map(list,tmp1['index'].items()),[]))
```

---

```
print(filtered_df)

  Company  Cost  Refund
0       A    10       0
2       B    10       0
4       A   158       0
```