# How to assign a data frame to a variable depending on two or more colums condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Am not sure if my quest is well framed but here it is.

here in this code i read the csv file and assign it to the variable australia_analysis specifying that the location column should be AUS

[image]

this is the output when i print it

[image]

How can i assign the dataframe to the variable under two conditions that the location should be AUS and the subject should be MEASLES so that i only get rows that satisfy the condition

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas: Filtering multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48978550/pandas-filtering-multiple-conditions)

Answer (score 2):

You can combine multiple conditions with &:

```
loaded_data.loc[(loaded_data['LOCATION'] == 'AUS') & (loaded_data['SUBJECT'] == 'MEASLES')]
```

Comment: This right here actually worked! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can filter based on multiple columns using this code

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([{"a":1,"b":1},{"a":1,"b":2},{"a":2,"b":2},{"a":2,"b":1}])
df2 = df[(df["a"] ==1) & (df["b"]==2)]
```