# Count ocurrencies of pattern in pandas dataframe based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

Consider this dataframe:

```
pd.DataFrame(['A(3)BC(1)', 'A(2)BC(5)', 'A(1)BC(3)', 'A(2)BC(5)', 'A(4)BC(2)'], columns=['Column1'])

    Column1
0   A(3)BC(1)
1   A(2)BC(5)
2   A(1)BC(3)
3   A(2)BC(5)
4   A(4)BC(2)
```

Is there a way to count the number of times A has a number higher than (3) without iterating through every line of the dataframe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try

```py
out = df['Column1'].str.extract('A\((\d+)\)')[0].astype(int).gt(3).sum()
```

```
print(out)

1
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Is it possible to make a combination of A and B? To find A>3 and B<5?

Comment: @LucasLazari You can similarly extract `B` times and check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48978550/pandas-filtering-multiple-conditions.

Answer (score 1):

If the format is always A(X) at the start, you can do:

`df['Column1'].apply(lambda st: int(st[st.find("A")+2:st.find(")")])).gt(3).sum()`

Output

`1`